# Exporting internal libraries when compiling with webpack 2

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

I'm in the process of converting one of our libraries to use webpack (we're moving the code from ES5 to ES6 but still have to deploy the library with ES5 support).

The library is internal and currently we just deploy it with the source, so in another library where it's used we can do this:

```
const library = require('library');
const dataSource = require('library/src/datasources/fooSource');
```

However now with a single file export, the second line no longer works.  I've tried adding the folders to the resolve.modules, however this doesn't appear to work.

The webpack config looks like this, possibly if we can do the same as above (but remove the `/src` part of it)?

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const packageJSON = require('./package.json');

const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  name: 'engine',
  entry: {
      'engine': ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
      'engine-iframe': ['babel-polyfill', './src/index-iframe.js'],
  },
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'sourcemap',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [
        'node_modules',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/core'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/datasource'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/events'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/plugins'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/strategies'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/util')
    ]
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin('./dist'),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner:
       `/**
         * ${packageJSON.name} - Copyright © ${new Date().getFullYear()}
         * Version ${packageJSON.value}
         * ${packageJSON.homepage}
         */
        `,
      raw: true,
      entryOnly: false
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        cacheDirectory: true
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: Usually your library does expose some entities, which can be used by end user, so just re-export them in main library entrypoint as ES6 named export, to use it then like this `export Lib, { DataSources } from 'your-lib'`

More than, you can customize webpack external dependencies in custom way by `external` section, written by callback function, which can return requested module content in async way

Answer (score 1):

The module you import/require refers to a path. A library cannot change that behaviour, the only way is to provide these files in addition to the bundled version. A great example of a library doing this is Redux, which has a [simple build step](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/887bf072bbd5eb354f2e2bd2fbd3a4deb8ef1e90/package.json#L22-L26). It's using babel to transpile the code and [Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) for the bundle instead of webpack, but the concept is the same.
Redux publishes the following structure (see [unpkg - Redux](https://unpkg.com/redux@3.7.2/) for the full source):

```
├─ dist
│  ├── redux.js
│  └── redux.min.js
├─ es
│  ├── applyMiddleware.js
│  ...
└─ lib
  ├── applyMiddleware.js
  ...
```

In the `dist/` directory there are the bundled files (regular and minified). In `lib/` there is the transpiled code, that is expected to run in Node without any additional tooling, and `es/` which is the same as `lib/` except that it uses ES modules, whereas `lib/` transpiled that to `require`. With that you could import/require `redux/lib/applyMiddleware` etc.

You can do something similar, where you transpile the code with babel (if you want to use some newer features), such that you can directly import what you need and use the bundle as the main entry point.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're really after is the ES2015 -> ES5 transpilation, and want to retain the old structure (and simply grabbing from modules within it), maybe using babel as a standalone tool will be preferable in this case?

e.g. `babel -d dist/ src/`